# is it possible to host a vpn server using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vpn

I was just wondering if it's possible to host a VPN server using node js? This will make it very easy to create restrictions for the connection or block certain websites for example...

I can't find an npm package for hosting a vpn server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

One of the solutions that I would suggest is:

1. To install [**openvpn**](https://openvpn.net/). And to use and node client to interact with the **openvpn** server
2. Npm package https://github.com/luigiplr/node-openvpn